# import javascript variable as constant angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import a JS variable as a constant into my application, as I am unable to use conventional JSON methods.

I have this code:

```
//english.js
var english = {"title-1": "Some text"};
export { english as default };
```

And am importing it like this:

```
import { english } from '../path/english.js';

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])

   .constant('english', english)
```

And then trying to use it like this:

```
export class AController {
  constructor($scope, english) {
    'ngInject';
    this.data = english; //undefined 
    ....
```

What am I doing wrong here? english is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want english to be the **default** export, you need the `default` keyword and should have the following structure:

```
//english.js
var english = {"title-1": "Some text"};
export default english;
```

and you would import it without the `{}` like so:

```
import english from '../path/english';
```

To have `english` simply be one of exported items you would leave off the `default` keyword.

```
//english.js
export var english = {"title-1": "Some text"};
```

and to import it, the `{}` are required.

```
import {english} from '../path/english';
```

So in your case, either remove the `default` keyword when you export it, **or** remove the `{}` when you import it.

[import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) documentation from mdn.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need `default`

Try `export {english};` instead. Sometimes when I am not sure what ES6 does, I try using [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl) which helps me a lot to understand what I actually did.

Answer (score 0):

Your export of `english` object is invalid since you are using named export. You can improve this by doing:

```
export const english = {"copy":"example"};
```